# Magento category module shows HTML code instead of buttons

Tags: magento, categories

[image: Magento backend category screenshot]

I am facing this issue since last few hours.  I haven't done any changes and can't recall if any specific action caused this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

the allow_html_tags_on_frontend flag for that attribute was set to 0 – ie. don’t allow HTML.

**fix:**
Updating this flag directly in the database table catalog_eav_attribute fixed the issue immediately.

Just find your attribute_id in eav_attributes for the given attribute code and locate it in the above table. Use PHPMyAdmin or similar to update the database manually.